# How to find minimum longitude of coordinate system?

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, arcmap, epsg

I have to write a function in Python which takes list of coordinates and a coordinate reference system (as EPSG code). It should return True if the coordinates are valid in the coordinate system, or False if not. How can I do that?

My idea was to get min and max latitude and longitude, create a bonding polygon and check if point falls inside. Problem is I don't know how to get min and max lat and lon from EPSG code. My only idea is to write them manually into function which is rather pointless.

Is this the right approach or I'm overthinking it and there's an easier way?

So far I have:

```
def valid_coordinates(EPSG):
    print "Coordinate System : ", arcpy.SpatialReference(EPSG).name
    array = arcpy.Array([
        arcpy.Point(-180, -90),
        arcpy.Point(180, -90),
        arcpy.Point(-180, 90),
        arcpy.Point(180, 90),
        arcpy.Point(-180, -90),
        ])# build a polygon based on the array 
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array, EPSG)
    point_1 = Point(-0.4, 30.3) 
    point_2 = Point(-1000,-5000)
    print "Point 1: ", polygon.contains(point_1) #returns True which is correct
    print "Point 2: ", polygon.contains(point_2) #returns False is correct
```

but this is pointless as function should take any coordinates and any EPSG

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I did a quick Google Search on "EPSG python" and found the [`python-epsg`](https://github.com/geo-data/python-epsg#querying-the-registry) library where the last bullet of this example sounds like what you need.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Achieve this with `len()`:

```
latitude = 'your_extension' len(latitude)
```